# Limitation of comparing functions using asymptotic notation?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am studying Algorithms on my own from the CLRS book, i.e. Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen etc. I need help to understand some math in the book.

The book says that the functions $$ n $$ and $$ n^{1+\sin (n)} $$ cannot be compared using asymptotic notation, since the value of the exponent in the latter function oscillates between 0 and 2, taking on all values in between.

Why can the two functions not be compared using asymptotic notation ? Can someone please explain in more detail, preferably with a diagram ?

Thank you.

Comment: It's rather simple: if $n^{1+\sin n}$ were $O(n)$, their ratio $n^{\sin n}$ would be bounded as $n\to\infty$, which it isn't. No diagram is necessary for that.

Comment: @Bernard - Could you please explain in more detail with steps ? Thanks.

Comment: Do you agree that $n ^{\sin n}$ should be bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large $n$ you cannot say that one graph dominates the other.

[image]

Click for a closer look. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uhvcmgxyg1